# Congruence properties of binary partition function

Tags: integer-partitions, congruence-relations

For every positive integer $n$, denote $b(n)$ be the number of binary partition of $n$, i.e., the number of partition of $n$ into power of two, where the power is decreasing.
For instance, $b(5)=4$ since
\begin{align*}
&2^2+2^0, \\
&2^1+2^1+2^0, \\
&2^1+2^0+2^0+2^0, \\
&2^0+2^0+2^0+2^0.
\end{align*}
Also, for convenience, we set $b(0)=1$.

I want to show the following congruences:
$$b(2^{2k+2}n)-b(2^{2k}n) \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{3k+2}}$$
and
$$b(2^{2k+1}n)-b(2^{2k-1}n) \equiv 0 \pmod{2^{3k}}$$
for every positive integer $k$ and any positive integer $n$, using mathematical induction on $n$ and $k$.

Given that $b(n)$ have some relations:

1. $b(2n+1)=b(2n)$;
2. $b(2n)=b(2n-2)+b(n)$;
3. $b(2^mn)=\sum_{j=0}^{n} C_m(j)b(n-j)$,

for every positive integer $n$, where $C_{m+1}(j)=\sum_{i=0}^{2j}C_m(i)$, $C_1(j)=1$ for all $j \ge 0$, and $C_m(0)=1$ for all $m \ge 1$.

I want to prove the first congruence only, and the rest should follows.

By the third relation, I want to prove that
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} (C_{2k+2}(j)-C_{2k}(j))b(n-j) \equiv 0 \pmod {2^{3k+2}}. \tag{1}$$

For the base case, i.e., for $k=1=n$, we have
$$\sum_{j=0}^{1} (C_{4}(j)-C_{2}(j))b(1-j) = (C_4(0)-C_2(0))b(1)+(C_4(1)-C_2(1))b(0)
= 35-3 = 32 \equiv 0 \pmod {2^{3(1)+2}}.$$

For the inductive step, assume that Congruence $(1)$ holds.
Want to show that it is also hold for $k+1$ and $n+1$, that is,
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n} (C_{2k+4}(j)-C_{2k+2}(j))b(n-j) \equiv 0 \pmod {2^{3k+5}}. \tag{2}$$
and
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n+1} (C_{2k+2}(j)-C_{2k}(j))b(n+1-j) \equiv 0 \pmod {2^{3k+2}}. \tag{3}$$
also holds.

But, I got stucked here and confusing what I should do.
Any idea please? I need a help to show these congruences. Also, if any, I would very appreciated for another approach than using induction (simple and easy to understanding).
Many thanks in advanced.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A018819](https://oeis.org/A018819) and links there.

Comment: In particular, the papers of Alkauskas referred to there seem quite relevant.

Comment: Your last partition of five adds up to four.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Section 10.2 Rödseth's Theorem for Binary Partitions of *[The Theory of Partitions](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/theory-of-partitions/7BC70DD4C1A06AA6179CEDEAD2F0C2DC)* by G. Andrews we find the following:

- [G. Andrews]: ... The theorem above allows us to prove certain congruences for $b(4n)-b(n)$ originally conjectured by R. F. Churchhouse and proved independently by O. Rödseth and H. Gupta.

> *Theorem 10.2*: If $k\geq 1$ and $n  \equiv 1 \pmod {2}$, then
> \begin{align*}
>    b(2^{2k+2}n)-b(2^kn)&\equiv 0 \pmod {2^{3k+2}}\tag{10.2.9}\\
>    b(2^{2k+1}n)-b(2^{2k-1}n)&\equiv 0 \pmod {2^{3k}}\tag{10.2.10}\\
>    \end{align*}
>
> furthermore, (10.2.9) and (10.2.10) are best possible in that no higher power of $2$ divides $b(4n)-b(n)$.

The proof presented by G. Andrews is a proof by induction based on generating functions. Here I give some of the main ideas of the proof without going into all the details, since it is somewhat lengthy and technical.

**Introduction:** We define a generating function $B(q)$ for the $b(n), n\geq 0$ as
\begin{align*}
B(q)&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b(n)q^n\\
&=\left(1+q+q^2+\cdots\right)\left(1+q^2+q^4+\cdots\right)\left(1+q^4+q^8+\cdots\right)\cdots\\
&=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{2^{n}}}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
In order to work with generating functions to cope with expressions (10.2.9) and (10.2.10) we introduce an operator $U_m, m\geq 1$ as:
\begin{align*}
U_m\left(A\left(q\right)\right)=U_m\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nq^n\right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{mn}q^n
\end{align*}
Looking at (10.2.9) and (10.2.10) we take the operator $U_n$ and define a generating function $\mathcal{F}_m(q)$ as
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}_m(q)&=\left(U_{2^{m+1}}-U_{2^{m-1}}\right)B(q)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(b\left(2^{m+1}n\right)-b\left(2^{m-1}n\right)\right)q^n\tag{2}
\end{align*}

**Claim reformulated:** We can now state the claim formulated in theorem 10.2 in terms of generating functions.

- In order to show (10.2.10) we consider for $k\geq 1$:
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{2^{-3k}\mathcal{F}_{2k}(q)}&=2^{-3k}\left(U_{2^{2k+1}}-U_{2^{2k-1}}\right)B(q)\\
  &\,\,\color{blue}{=2^{-3k}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(b\left(2^{2k+1}n\right)-b\left(2^{2k-1}n\right)\right)q^n}\tag{3}
  \end{align*}
  and show that $2^{-3k}\mathcal{F}_{2k}(q)$ has integral coefficients only.
- In order to show (10.2.9) we consider for $k\geq 1$:
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{2^{-3k-2}\mathcal{F}_{2k+1}(q)}&=2^{-3k-2}\left(U_{2^{2k+2}}-U_{2^{2k}}\right)B(q)\\
  &\,\,\color{blue}{=2^{-3k-2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(b\left(2^{2k+2}n\right)-b\left(2^{2k}n\right)\right)q^n}\tag{4}
  \end{align*}
  and show that $2^{-3k-2}\mathcal{F}_{2k+1}(q)$ has integral coefficients only.

**Base step: $k=1$**

We now show the claim for (3) and (4) for $k=1$. We want to calculate $\mathcal{F}_2$ and $\mathcal{F}_3$ and have at first to start with the calculation of $\mathcal{F}_1$.

> **Intermezzo I: Calculation of $\mathcal{F}_1(q)$:**
> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathcal{F}_{1}\left(q^4\right)}&=\left(U_{2^{4}}-U_{2^{0}}\right)B\left(q^4\right)\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(b(4n)-b(n)\right)q^{4n}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^3B\left(i^jq\right)-B\left(q^4\right)\tag{5.1}\\
> &=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^3\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-i^{j2^{n}}q^{2^{n}}}-\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{2^{n+2}}}\tag{5.2}\\
> &=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{2^{n}}}\left(\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^3\frac{1}{\left(1-i^{j}q\right)\left(1-i^{2j}q^2\right)}-1\right)\tag{5.3}\\
> &=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{2^{n}}}\left(\frac{1}{4}\sum_{j=0}^3
> \frac{\left(1+i^jq\right)\left(1+i^{2j}q^2\right)}{\left(1-q^4\right)^2}-1\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{\left(1-q^4\right)^2}\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{2^{n}}}\left(1+q^4-\left(1-q^4\right)^2\right)\\
> &=\frac{q^4\left(3-q^4\right)}{\left(1-q^4\right)^3}\prod_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{2^{n}}}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{q^4\left(3-q^4\right)}{\left(1-q^4\right)^3}\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-\left(q^4\right)^{2^{n}}}}\tag{5.4}\\
> \end{align*}
> Substituting $q^4\to q$ in (5.4) gives:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathcal{F}_1(q)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{q(3-q)}{(1-q)^3}G(q)}\tag{5.5}\\
> \color{blue}{G(q)}&\color{blue}{=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{2^{n}}}=(1-q)B(q)}\tag{5.6}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (5.1) we use *[multisection of series](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesMultisection.html)*.
- In (5.2) we use the series representation (1) for $B(q)$.
- In (5.3) we factor out the common product $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{2^{n}}}$.

**Base step $k=1$ (continued):**

We calculate $\mathcal{F}_2$ with the help of $\mathcal{F}_1$ as
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\mathcal{F}_2\left(q^2\right)}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathcal{F}_1(q)+\mathcal{F}_1(-q)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}qG(q)\left(\frac{3-q}{(1-q)^3}-\frac{3+q}{(1+q)^3}\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{8q^2G(q)}{\left(1-q^2\right)^3}}\\
\color{blue}{\mathcal{F}_2(q)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{8qG(q)}{(1-q)^4}}\tag{6}
\end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (6) we use
  \begin{align*}
  G\left(q^2\right)=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{2^{n+1}}}=\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-q^{2^{n}}}=\left(1-q^2\right)G(q)
  \end{align*}

In a similar way we derive
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\mathcal{F}_3\left(q^2\right)}&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathcal{F}_2(q)+\mathcal{F}_2(-q)\right)\\
&=\frac{4qG(q)}{\left(1-q^2\right)^4}\left((1+q)^4-(1-q)^4\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{32q^2G(q)\left(1+q^2\right)}{\left(1-q^2\right)^4}}\\
\color{blue}{\mathcal{F}_3(q)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{32qG(q)(1+q)}{(1-q)^5}}\tag{7}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (6) and (7)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{8}\mathcal{F}_{2}(q)}&=\frac{qG(q)}{(1-q)^4}
> =\frac{qB(q)}{(1-q)^3}\tag{8.1}\\
> &\equiv\frac{q}{(1-q)^2}\equiv\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}q^{2j+1}\pmod{2}}\tag{8.2}\\
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{32}\mathcal{F}_{3}(q)}&=\frac{qG(q)(1+q)}{(1-q)^5}
> =\frac{qB(q)(1+q)}{(1-q)^4}\equiv\frac{qB(q)}{(1-q)^3}\tag{8.3}\\
> &\equiv\frac{q}{(1-q)^2}
> \equiv\color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}q^{2j+1}\pmod{2}}\tag{8.2}\\
> \end{align*}
> and the claim for $k=1$ follows. We note  that thanks to the right-hand representation $\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}q^{2j+1}\pmod{2}$ we have additionally shown that no higher power of $2$ divides $b(4n)-b(n)$ as claimed in Theorem 10.2 above.

*Comment:*

- In (8.1) we use the identity (5.6).
- In (8.2) we note the sequence $(b(n))_{n\geq 0}=(1,1,2,2,4,4,6,6,10,10,14,14,\ldots)$ stored as *[A018819](https://oeis.org/A018819)* in OEIS has even entries for $n\geq 2$. It follows for example from the first few entries of the sequence together with the identities
  \begin{align*}
  b(2n+1)&=b(2n)\\
  b(2n)&=b(2n-2)+b(n)
  \end{align*}
  stated as 1.) and 2.) by OP (and easily verified using the generating function $G(q)$). It follows that
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{1-q}B(q)&=\frac{1}{1-q}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b(n)q^n\\
  &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{j=0}^nb(j)\right)q^n
  \equiv b(0)\equiv 1\pmod{2}
  \end{align*}
- In (8.3) we also use
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1+q}{1-q}&=\left(1+q+q^2+q^3+\cdots\right)+\left(q+q^2+q^3+q^4\cdots\right)\\
  &=1+2q+2q^2+2q^3+\cdots\equiv 1\pmod{2}
  \end{align*}

**Intermezzo II: Another relationship between $\mathcal{F}_m(q)$ and $G(q)$:**

In Order to prove the *induction step* we need a formula in terms of the generating functions $\mathcal{F}_m$ and $G(q)$ corresponding to OPs stated formula 3.). We can derive from (6) and (7) after some calculations
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}_3(q)+4\mathcal{F}_2(q)&=\frac{64qG(q)}{(1-q)^5}\tag{9}\\
\end{align*}
and applying $U_2$ to (9)
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}_4(q)+16\mathcal{F}_3(q)+40\mathcal{F_2}(q)&=\frac{1024qG(q)}{(1-q)^6}
\end{align*}

- This can be generalized and is stated by G. Andrews as Theorem 10.1.

  *Theorem 10.1*: There exist integers $c_j(m)$ such that for $m\geq 2$
  \begin{align*}
     \color{blue}{\sum_{j=0}^{m-2}c_j(m)\mathcal{F}_{m-j}(q)=\frac{2^{\binom{m+1}{2}}qG(q)}{(1-q)^{m+2}}}\tag{10}
     \end{align*}

  furthermore, $c_0(m)=1, 16|c_1(m)$ if $m\geq 4, 8|c_2(m), 16 \not|\;\;\; c_2(m)$, and $2^{2j}|c_j(m)$, for $3\leq j\leq m-2$.

The following induction step is nearly verbatim from the book.

> **Induction step:**
>
> We are now ready to prove the induction step. Assuming that Theorem 10.2 is true for all integers less than $k$.
>
> - Then by Theorem 10.1 we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
>   2^{-3k}&\mathcal{F}_{2k}(q)+2^{-3k}c_1(2k)\mathcal{F}_{2k-1}(q)+2^{-3k}c_2(2k)\mathcal{F}_{2k-2}(q)\\
>   &+\sum_{j=3}^{2k-2}2^{-3k}c_j(2k)\mathcal{F}_{2k-j}(q)
>   =\frac{2^{\binom{2k+1}{2}-3k}qG(q)}{(1-q)^{2k+2}}
>   \end{align*}
>   By Theorem 10.1, $16|c_1(2k), 8|c_2(2k)$, and $2^{2j}|c_j(2k)$, also for $k>1$,
>   \begin{align*}
>   \binom{2k+1}{2}-3k>0
>   \end{align*}
>   Hence from the induction hypothesis we see that $2^{-3k}\mathcal{F}_{2k}(q)$ has integral coefficients. Furthermore since $16 \not|\;\;\; c_2(2k)$,
>   \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{2^{-3k}\mathcal{F}_{2k}(q)\equiv2^{-3k+3}\mathcal{F}_{2k-2}(q)\equiv\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}q^{2j+1}\pmod{2}}
>   \end{align*}
>   and the claim (3) which is the reformulated claim (10.2.10) follows.
> - Now by Theorem 10.1 we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
>   2^{-3k-2}&\mathcal{F}_{2k+1}(q)+2^{-3k-2}c_1(2k+1)\mathcal{F}_{2k}(q)
>   +2^{-3k-2}c_2(2k+1)\mathcal{F}_{2k-1}(q)\\
>   &+\sum_{j=3}^{2k-2}2^{-3k-2}c_j(2k+1)\mathcal{F}_{2k+1-j}(q)
>   =\frac{2^{\binom{2k+2}{2}-3k-2}qG(q)}{(1-q)^{2k+3}}
>   \end{align*}
>   Again by Theorem 10.1, $16|c_1(2k+1), 8|c_2(2k+1), 2^{2j}|c_j(2k)$, also for $k>1$,
>   \begin{align*}
>   \binom{2k+2}{2}-3k-2>0
>   \end{align*}
>   Hence from the induction hypothesis we see that $2^{-3k-2}\mathcal{F}_{2k+1}(q)$ has integral coefficients. Furthermore since $16 \not|\;\;\; c_2(2k+1)$,
>   \begin{align*}
>   \color{blue}{2^{-3k-2}\mathcal{F}_{2k+1}(q)\equiv2^{-3k+1}\mathcal{F}_{2k-1}(q)\equiv\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}q^{2j+1}\pmod{2}}
>   \end{align*}
>   and the claim (4) which is the reformulated claim (10.2.9) follows.
>   \begin{align*}
>   \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\Box
>   \end{align*}

---

**Add-on:** With respect to OPs comment we consider the induction hypothesis and analyse in detail that $2^{-3k}\mathcal{F}_{2k}(q)$ has integral coefficients. From (10) we obtain letting $m=2k$ for $k\geq 1$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{j=0}^{2k-2}c_j(2k)\mathcal{F}_{2k-j}(q)=\frac{2^{\binom{2k+1}{2}}qG(q)}{(1-q)^{2k+2}}\tag{11}
\end{align*}
We multiply (11) with $2^{-3k}$ and separate from the left-hand sum the first three terms. We obtain
\begin{align*}
2^{-3k}&\mathcal{F}_{2k}(q)+2^{-3k}c_1(2k)\mathcal{F}_{2k-1}(q)+2^{-3k}c_2(2k)\mathcal{F}_{2k-2}(q)\\
&+\sum_{j=3}^{2k-2}2^{-3k}c_j(2k)\mathcal{F}_{2k-j}(q)
=\frac{2^{\binom{2k+1}{2}-3k}qG(q)}{(1-q)^{2k+2}}\tag{12}
\end{align*}

- We start with $\mathcal{F}_{2k-2}(q)$: We know from (3) and the induction hypthesis by taking $k-1$ that
  \begin{align*}
  2^{-3(k-1)}\mathcal{F}_{2(k-1)}(q)=2^{-3k}\cdot 8\mathcal{F}_{2k-2}(q)
  \end{align*}
  has integral coefficients. Since we know from Theorem 10.1 that $8|c_2(2k)$ it follows
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{2^{-3k}c_2(2k)\mathcal{F}_{2k-2}(q)}
  \end{align*}
  has integral coefficients.
- Now we look at $\mathcal{F}_{2k-1}(q)$: We know from (4) and the induction hypothesis by taking $k-1$ that
  \begin{align*}
  2^{-3(k-1)-2}\mathcal{F}_{2(k-1)+1}(q)=2^{-3k}\cdot 2\mathcal{F}_{2k-1}(q)
  \end{align*}
  has integral coefficients. Since we know from Theorem 10.1 that $16|c_1(2k)$ it follows
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{2^{-3k}c_1(2k)\mathcal{F}_{2k-1}(q)}
  \end{align*}
  has integral coefficients.
- Next we consider the terms $\mathcal{F}_{2k-2j}, j\geq 1$ of the sum with even index. We know from (3) and the induction hypothesis by taking $k-j$ that
  \begin{align*}
  2^{-3(k-j)}\mathcal{F}_{2(k-j)}(q)=2^{-3k}\cdot 2^{3j}\mathcal{F}_{2k-2j}(q)
  \end{align*}
  has integral coefficients. Since we know from Theorem 10.1 that $2^{4j}|c_{2j}(2k)$ it follows
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{2^{-3k}c_{2j}(2k)\mathcal{F}_{2k-2j}(q)}
  \end{align*}
  has integral coefficients.
- Now we consider the terms $\mathcal{F}_{2k-2j-1}, j\geq 1$ of the sum with odd index. We know from (4) and the induction hypothesis by taking $k-j$ that
  \begin{align*}
  2^{-3(k-j-1)-2}\mathcal{F}_{2(k-j)-1}(q)=2^{-3k}\cdot 2^{3j+1}\mathcal{F}_{2k-2j-1}(q)
  \end{align*}
  has integral coefficients. Since we know from Theorem 10.1 that $2^{4j+2}|c_{2j+1}(2k)$ it follows
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{2^{-3k}c_{2j+1}(2k)\mathcal{F}_{2k-2j-1}(q)}
  \end{align*}
  has integral coefficients.
- Finally we note that for $k>1$ we obtain
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{2k+2}{2}-3k-2>0
  \end{align*}
  and it follows
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\frac{2^{\binom{2k+2}{2}-3k-2}qG(q)}{(1-q)^{2k+3}}}
  \end{align*}
  is a generating function with integral coefficients.

We conclude from (12) and the derivations above $2^{-3k}\mathcal{F}_{2k}(q)$ has integral coefficients and the induction hypothesis is shown for it. Similarly we derive that $2^{-3k-2}\mathcal{F}_{2k+1}(q)$ has integral coefficients.

Comment: It will take a while to read. Let me upvote first for the great effort to explain the main ideas.

Comment: @Apass.Jack: Manyy thanks for your nice comment. It was interesting and a pleasure for me to go through the proof. Here I provide all information you need to understand it, i.e. to understand Theorem 10.2. besides a proof of Theorem 10.1 which is used for the induction step. A nice aspect here is, that when using a proof based upon generating functions it is sufficient to show induction on one variable $k$ only.

Comment: @epi163sqrt What a brilliant answer! But, I didn't know yet some statement like:
"Hence from the induction hypothesis we see that $2^{-3k}F_2k(q)$
 has integral coefficients." Could you explain this before I accept this answer please? Which induction hypothesis used there?

Comment: @Many thanks for your nice comment and for granting the bounty. :-) I will add some information after work. Kind regards,

Comment: Very welcome, Sir. Also, could you explain to me about the proof of the Theorem 10.1 please? I'm confuse starting from the inductive step, especially, forming the integer $\delta_k(m+2)$. I very need a help. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: @sqrtpi: I've added some more details which might be helpful to follow the proof.

Comment: @sqrtpi: $\delta_k(m+2)$ are simply defined integral coefficients of a polynomial. I suggest that you formulate your difficulties in understanding Theorem 10.1 more precisely and ask for advice in a separate question. Kind regards,

Comment: @epi163sqrt Sir. Could you explain me about my new question below, please?
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4635539/understanding-a-proof-related-to-binary-partitions

Comment: @sqrtpi: I will provide an answer on the weekend, if there is no other helpful answer by then.

Comment: @epi163sqrt I really appreciate your help, Sir. I really really appreciate it, and tbh, really needs your help. Thanks you so much.